# Are there any must read physics books for beginners?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I am in 9th grade and have recently become interested in physics. I have a basic understand of relativity, electromagnetism, and a bit of knowledge about on quantum mechanics. However, I don't have much of an understanding at all about the mathematic of these subjects and would like to learn. I am just starting geometry and have completed algebra. Any suggestions for books or online recources to help me?

Comment: There are must read physics books, but you are not quite far enough in your studies to read them, unless you are unusually advanced. If you haven't had calculus, yet, it's kind of difficult to even talk about dynamics in classical mechanics and it's really impossible to talk about electrodynamics without multivariate calculus. Focus on those, once you master them, then you can start reading the serious physics books. If you need one title that is a must read, I would put Landau, Lifshitz "Volume 1: Mechanics" on your list. It's online... take a peek, it shows what theoretical physics is like.

Comment: Have you asked your teacher?  Have you looked in your school library?  Your teacher will have a much better idea than we do what is appropriate for you.

Comment: "Visual Complex Analysis"

Comment: Would be nice to know what question this is a duplicate of.